# Clear and Redraw with Cappuccino (Objective-J)

Tags: cappuccino, objective-j

basically I have this

```
@implementation MyView : CPView
{
  CPArray MyPanelArray;
}

// Populate the MyPanelArray and position each panel
- (void)initMyView
{
  ...
}
```

MyPanels are pretty much wrappers for images.  When everything is initialized it draws just fine.  Then I have a slider to manipulate the position of the images and the only way I know how to redraw everything is to overwrite the MyView with a new instance and in the main contentView do something like

```
// Has the correct effect, but feels wrong
- (void)sliderAction:(id)sender
{
    var myNewView = [MyView initWithPositionValue:[sender value]];
    [_contentView replaceSubview:_myView with:myNewView];
    _myView = myNewView;
}
```

It works all right, but I doubt thats the "right way".

*I know I can use a CPCollectionView for a basic setup, but its not going to work for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

By "redraw" do you mean actually doing a drawRect: or just moving/resizing the image views? If it's the latter then you can just call setFrame: on _myView.

Comment: Wow! Its you, Francisco.  Cool.  Um, yeah.  More simply the problem is that I'm trying to recreate the coverflow effect.  I adjust the slider and I need all the images to change position and/or be sheared by an affine transform.  I haven't started with animating it, just jumping to new positions.  When the slider was adjusted, it would reposition everything and redraw on top of the old state before I tried the replaceSubview:with:.

Comment: You should find me on IRC (#cappuccino on freenode) so we can just hack on the code together a bit and I can see what's going on in more context, then we can post the solution back here. I can tell you that if you're going to want to apply affine transform you'll want to use CALayers at some point (which are designed to handle transforms)